# finding if the strings in an array is exists in another array

Tags: java, arrays, string

i have an array `String[] questions={"adorable", "able", "adventurous"};` and i also have an array t[] with that contains all adjectives. i would like to find the words adorable, able and adventurous in array t[]. so far i have this line codes but it doesn't seem to work. can someone please help me?

```
    String u = sn.nextLine();
    String[] t = u.split(" ");
    for (y = 0; y <= question.length; y++) {
        for (int w = 0; w < t.length; w++) {
            if (t[w].equals(question[y])) {
                System.out.print(t[w] + " ");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The terminating condition in the outer `for` is incorrect, and will go beyond the bounds of the `question` array: use `<` not `<=`.

Comment: This is OK only if you are absolutely indifferent to performance. It could be sped up by a factor commensurate with the size of your adjectives dictionary, and with less code at that.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" how?

Comment: i tried debugging it but it doesn't give me any output

Comment: i removed the = but it still doesn't produce any output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do :

```
for (int y = 0; y < question.length; y++) {

}
```

instead of `<=`. The problem outcomes from the fact you don't have a `question[question.length]` element.

Also, I don't see where you declare the `y` variable.

**Update:** Here's a complete sample:

```
String[] questions = {"adorable", "able", "adventurous"};
String u = "able adorable asd";
String[] t = u.split(" ");
for (int y = 0; y < questions.length; y++) {
   for (int w = 0; w < t.length; w++) {
       if (t[w].equals(questions[y])) {
           System.out.print(t[w] + " ");
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
adorable able
```

Comment: i removed the equal sign but it still doesn't produce any output :/

Comment: Make sure the `u` variable is not empty.

Comment: i tried to debug it and variable u is not empty. so as String[] t

Answer (score 4):

What about this:

```
Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(t));
Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(questions));

s1.retainAll(s2);
```

Now `s1` contains all the strings in `t` that also appear in `question`.

---

For example:

```
String[] t = "Hello, world! I am adventurous and adorable!".split("\\W+");
String[] questions = {"adorable", "able", "adventurous"};

Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(t));
Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(questions));

s1.retainAll(s2);
System.out.println(s1);
```

```
[adventurous, adorable]
```

Comment: actually the strings from question already exists in t. i was just trying to debug the program to see if it works properly

Answer (score 1):

```
for(String question: questions){

    for(String word: t){

        if(question.equals(word)){

             //Do somethin

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i applied what you suggested by it didn't give me any output

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a data structure, such as an ArrayList or LinkedList, instead of an array.

This way, you can just call contains().